# Add easing / animate upon hover so coloured div hides and image shows

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

http://jsfiddle.net/lxm7/Zzuq3/

I've had a look around at many similar solution but can't seem to find the answer. I basically just want an easing gradual effecting on the image when user hovers over the orange div. The snippet in jsfiddle below. I know this would have been answered before but its always hiding the image to reveal div and not the other way round.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd layer two divs on top of each other and use `animate()` to make the colored one fade out over time (and vice versa): http://jsfiddle.net/CLdP3/29/

There are more options to control the animate function, check the [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been trying around with opacities, mouseovers, .animate, .hover. with jquery but kept coming short of what i wanted. Newbie at js!

Comment: Here was my latest attempt before reading this post: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/lxm7/8zLqX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Anders Holmstrom beat me to it - I used the same basic approach, but used an absolutely positioned inner image and jQuery fadeIn() and fadeOut(). Check it out for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/AjXYK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery can only really animate elements with numeric values your best bet is to layer the image and color elements, and fade one in and out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/9xv4e/

The jsFiddle example above shows how you could do this. I created a color div that sits over the outer container. This color div will fade in and out as you hover. I then pulled the visible content over the color div by absolute positioning the visible div. Hope this helps some.